# Need a query to find employees that have not paid into retirement

Tags: sql

My first post here and hoping for some help. I have a need to create a report that shows employees that have never paid into retirement. I need to pull information from 3 tables. Employees have paid into retirement if they have specific deduction codes (7001 through 7006). I have the following tables and columns.

```
Employee
Employee.empid
Employee.fname
Employee.lname
Employee.jobclass


EarnHistory
EarnHistory.empid
EarnHistory.hoursworked
EarnHistory.checknumber
EarnHistory.checkdate


DeductionHistory
DeductionHistory.empid
DeductionHistory.deductioncode
DeductionHistory.checknumber
DeductionHistory.checkdate
```

Query needs to pull in empid, fname, lname, hoursworked, deductioncode
Where the employee has never paid into deduction code 7001 through 7006.

I've tried unsuccessfully to use NOT EXISTS

Comment: Which SQL Server? Any [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: You should include your query that didn't work, that way someone can try to explain why it didn't work and a better way to do it.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Your right, I should have posted the original query. I'll post the query when I get back to the office.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT E.empid, E.fname, E.lname, EH.hoursworked, DH.deductioncode
FROM Employee E
   INNER JOIN EarnHistory EH ON E.empid = EH.empid
   INNER JOIN DeductionHistory DH ON E.empid = DH.empid
   LEFT JOIN DeductionHistory DH2 ON E.empid = DH2.empid 
       AND DH2.deductioncode IN (7001,7002,7003,7004,7005,7006)
WHERE DHD2.empid IS NULL
```

This depends on your deductioncode data type.  You could use BETWEEN, <>, or add apostrophes if varchar.

You could also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT E.empid, E.fname, E.lname, EH.hoursworked, DH.deductioncode
FROM Employee E
   INNER JOIN EarnHistory EH ON E.empid = EH.empid
   INNER JOIN DeductionHistory DH ON E.empid = DH.empid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM DeductionHistory 
                  WHERE deductioncode IN (7001,7002,7003,7004,7005,7006)
                     AND E.empid = DeductionHistory.empid)
```

Good luck.

Comment: I'll give the NOT EXISTS clause a try. I forgot one more detail. I need to also limit the results to employees with certain types of pays. There is a column in the EarnHistory table called paytype and I need to limit the results to paytype 100 through 150.

Comment: Just add that in your WHERE criteria: WHERE EH.PayType BETWEEN 100 AND 150 AND (This assumes it's a numeric datatype)...  Alternatively you could chain it in your JOIN.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Employee.empid, Employee.fname , Employee.lname,EarnHistory.hoursworked,           DeductionHistory.deductioncode from Employee 
    join EarnHistory using('empid')  
    join DeductionHistory using('empid')  
    LEFT JOIN DeductionHistory dh ON Empployee.empid = dh.empid 
    AND DH.deductioncode IN (7001,.......,7006)
    WHERE DHD.empid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.empid, E.fname, E.lname, EH.hoursworked, DH.deductioncode
  FROM Employee E, EarnHistory EN, DeductionHistory DH
 WHERE E.empid = EH.empid
   AND E.empid = DH.empid
   AND E.empid <> (SELECT empid
                     FROM DedutionHistory
                    GROUP BY empid 
                   HAVING deductioncode >= 7001
                      AND deductioncode <= 7006)
```